# How is an array stored in memory?

Tags: memory-management

In an interest to delve deeper into how memory is allocated and stored, I have written an application that can scan memory address space, find a value, and write out a new value.

I developed a sample application with the end goal to be able to programatically locate my array, and overwrite it with a new sequence of numbers.  In this situation, I created a single dimensional array, with 5 elements, e.g.

```
int[] array = new int[] {8,7,6,5,4};
```

I ran my application and searched for a sequence of the five numbers above.  I was looking for any value that fell between 4 and 8, for a total of 5 numbers in a row.   Unfortunately, my sequential numbers within the array matched hundreds of results, as the numbers 4 through 8, in no particular sequence happened to be next to each other, in memory, in many situations.

Is there any way to distinguish that a set of numbers within memory, represents an array, not simply integers that are next to each other?  Is there any way of knowing that if I find a certain value, that the matching values proceeding it are that of an array?

I would assume that when I declare `int[] array`, its pointing at the first address of my array, which would provide some kind of meta-data to what existed in the array, e.g.

> ```
> 0x123456789 meta-data, 5 - 32 bit integers 
> 0x123456789 + 32 "8"
> 0x123456789 + 64 "7"
> 0x123456789 + 96 "6"
> 0x123456789 + 128 "5"
> 0x123456789 + 160 "4"
> ```

Am I way off base?

Comment: Huh? `int[] array = new array {8,7,6,5,4};`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Debug + Windows + Memory + Memory 1, set the Address field to "array".  You'll see this when you switch the view to "4-byte Integer":

```
0x018416BC  6feb2c84 00000005 00000008 00000007 00000006 00000005 00000004
```

The first address is the address of the object in the garbage collected heap, plus the part of the object header that's at a negative offset (syncblk index).  You cannot guess this value, the GC moves it around.  The 2nd hex number is the 'type handle' for the array type (aka method table pointer).  You cannot guess this value, type handles are created by the CLR on demand.  The 3rd number is the array length.  The rest of them are the array element values.

The odds of reliably finding this array back at runtime without a debugger are quite low.  There isn't much point in trying.

Comment: If the 3rd set of numbers represents the length of the array, and the proceeding numbers after it matched the target range of known numbers and length -- I can see that getting pretty close. For example, if I were to search for 000000FF, knowing I had a 255 in length array, and then tested the proceeding 255 numbers for a range I knew was in the array, such as 0-5, the odds of finding that exact combination elsewhere in the code seems like it would be slim.  The chances of matching it however would be less likely the smaller the array I declared.

Comment: Well, yes.  Addresses are a multiple of 4.  Ambiguity is the problem, you don't have anything to select the 'proper' one.  And as much as 2 billion bytes to search through.  VirtualQuery can cut that down, only consider read+write pages.

Comment: Modified my application with the 3rd number set you mentioned and a few other abstract search rules I defined to enumerate quickly and thouroughly through the processes address space. Found my array, and only my array, in a split second. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Don't. Array is stored on the heap and subject to re-location due to garbage collection. You have to use [fixed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) if you need to make sure memory is not moved in which can you can use but only very carefully.

If you are after high-performance arrays, use [stackalloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx9s2sy4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and use your code scheme.

Comment: I'm not going for anything here besides knowledge of how the above sample would be stored when declared.  Whatever happens to the array during GC is beyond the scope of what I'm asking.  Just looking for education. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly but [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rajeshvs/PointersInCSharp11112005051624AM/PointersInCSharp.aspx) seems to suggest that you can get a pointer to your array, with which i would think you can determine the actual address.

Answer (score 0):

Although I see you are using C# and, presumably, .NET, most of your question is in very general terms about memory. Keep mind that, in the most general sense, all memory is just bits whether that memory holds an array, strings, or code.

With that in mind, unless you can find tell-tale signs of your current platform's way of allocating different data types, there is no difference between memory that contains arrays, strings, or code.

Also, I wouldn't make any assumptions about if an array "points" to the first item in the array. Perhaps someone else can address this issue specifically, but I would assume some sort of header is involved.

Comment: Agreed.  I removed the C# tag.

Comment: In that case, I would say the answer to your question is no.

Answer (score -1):

Memory is not always stored contiguously. If you can ensure that it is, what you are asking is possible.

Comment: Arrays are stored contiguously in virtual memory.  Contiguous virtual memory doesn't mean contiguous physical memory, but I'd be very surprised if this "scanner application" is using physical addresses.  You'd only have to worry about details like that if using a hardware DMA engine to scan memory.